# Finding limit of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have difficulty in calculating the following limit.

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[-1,1]$, it is desired to find the following limit,

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n \int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}} f(x)(1-n|x|)dx$

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do we have anything like differentiability at $0$?

Comment: @DavidBowman No there is no other assumptions on $f$.

Comment: Hint: split the integral in two halves, that is on $[-\frac1n, 0]$ and $[0,\frac1 n]$. Then apply the mean value theorem for integral on each interval.

Comment: Hint: If you replace $f(x)$ with $(f(x) - f(0))$ you should be able to show that you can make that integral as small as you want (in absolute value) for large $n$, using the continuity of $f$ at $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit, call it L, is $f(0)$.  To see this, fix $\epsilon$.  Then, by continuity of $f$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ n > N \Rightarrow f(0) - \epsilon \le f(x) \le f(0)+ \epsilon $$ on the interval $I_n= [\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}] $.

Now, multiplying with $n(1-n|x|)$ and integrating over the interval $I_n= [\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}] $ we get that for all $n > N$,
$$(f(0)-\epsilon) \int_{I_n}   n(1-n|x|) \le     \int_{I_n}  f(x) n(1-n|x|) \le  (f(0)+\epsilon)\int_{I_n}  n(1-n|x|)$$ The integrals on each side are trivial to evaluate (hint: What’s the area of a triangle of height $n$ and base $\frac{2}{n}$?).

$$f(0)-\epsilon \le      n  \int_{I_n} f(x) (1-n|x|)  \le  f(0)+\epsilon  $$

Now, taking the limit,
$$ f(0)-\epsilon \le L \le  f(0)+\epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we have $$L = f(0)$$

**A couple of related notes for intuition**:

1. In kernel smoothing of functions, your function $n(1-n|x|)$ is called the [triangle kernel or the linear kerne](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_kde_1d.html)l.  As the kernel bandwidth goes to zero, convolution with it must reproduce the function value $f(0)$.
2. Also, more loosely speaking, the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ of your kernel is the [Dirac delta "function". Convolution by it recovers the function value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) at 0.

Comment: Plugging $f \equiv 1$ and calculating the integral explicitly gives $-2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so the limit is $-2 \neq 1 = f(0)$.

Comment: Not so, @GuidoA. Your step $2(\frac{1}{n} -n\frac{1}{2n^2}) = -\frac{2}{n}$ has a mistake.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n \int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}} f(x)(1-n|x|)dx = \\
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nf(\xi_n)\cdot\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-n|x|)dx
$$
by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals), for $\xi_n \in (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$. Now, since

$$
\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-n|x|)dx = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-nx)dx = 2(\frac{1}{n} -n\frac{1}{2n^2}) = \frac{1}{n}
$$

we have

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n \int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}} f(x)(1-n|x|)dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(\xi_n) = f(0)
$$

where the last equality holds because since $f$ is continuous and $\xi_n \to 0$, $f(\xi_n) \to 0$.

Comment: You have a typo as integral evaluates to $1/n$ rather than $-2/n$.

Comment: Good catch, thanks! Fixed it.